# Returning custom values after validation with javax validation

Tags: java, validation, annotations

I am trying to validate some fields using javax.validation package. I use annotations like the below and validation works fine -

```
@NotEmpty(message = "Product Name is required.")
    @Pattern(regexp = ALPHA_NUMERIC, flags = Pattern.Flag.CASE_INSENSITIVE, message = "ProductName must be alphanumeric.")
    @Size(min = 100, max = 100, message = "ProductName may have maximum 100 characters.")
    private String productName;
```

Validation returns me a list of ConstraintViolations. For my application the field (like productName here) corresponds to a column in a spreadsheet. I am storing the column names in an enum like below -

```
public enum columnLocations {

    productId("A"),
    producrtName("B"),
    productCode("C"),
    description("D"),

//getters and setters go here

}
```

How do I get the validation process to return the column value from this enum along with the ConstraintViolation or as a part of it? Is implementing the ConstraintViolation class a clean way to do it? If yes, I presume that would mean adding another String which stores the column value along with getters and setters. In that case, how do I tie this implementing class to the annotations on the field?

Thanks